# Opening a file from ListView on a MouseDoubleClick event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mouseevent

I am trying to create a windows explorer.
I have succeeded in populating the treeView and listView like windows explorer, but i am having a problem opening the file on double click from the listView.

This is what i have so far:

```
try
        {
            //clears the collection so the listview has only the files of the folder thats clicked on
            _fileDetails.Clear();


            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo( SelectedImagePath );
            FileInfo[] info = dirInfo.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in info)
            {
                //adds files to the collection with its properties
                _fileDetails.Add( new Details
                {
                    FileName = fileInfo.Name,
                    Size = fileInfo.Length.ToString(),
                    DateCreated = fileInfo.CreationTime.ToString(),
                    DateModified = fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToString(),
                    RevNumber = "?",
                    User = "?"
                } );

            }
        }
```

where fileDetails is my ObservableCollection.

The mouse event:

```
protected void HandleDoubleClick( object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e )
    {
        DependencyObject src = ( DependencyObject )( e.OriginalSource );
        while (!( src is Control ))
            src = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( src );
        MessageBox.Show( "*** Double clicked on a " + src.GetType().FullName +"********************" + sender.ToString() );
    }
```

The binding:

```
<ListView Height="335" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,12,12,0" Name="fileExplorerView" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="509" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=fileDetails}">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="HandleDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>

            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FileName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Size" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Size}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Date Created" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateCreated}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Time Created" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateModified}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Revision Number"  Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RevNumber}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Modified By" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User}"/>

            </GridView>

        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Instead of the messageBox in the mouse event, i will use a process to open the files.The problem is, i cant seem to figure out how to get the path of the selected file.

Thanks

All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
var item = (FrameworkElement)sender;
var file = (Details)item.DataContext;
var path = file.Path; // Your Details class should save the FileInfo.FullName!
```

*(Why do you have a `Details` class anyway? I would just use the `FileInfo` object)*